# Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn Angular and attempting to write my first controller outside of a web-based tutorial. I keep getting the error in the title in the JS console and can't figure out what's going on. The link takes me to a page referencing the need to include ngRoute, which I've done according to the API. Surely I'm missing something but I can't see what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

index.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>First Angular Project</title>
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-controller="FirstController">
            Did the controller load?
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('FirstController', function(){
        console.log("FirstController loaded");
    });
})
```

Comment: Is the loading of `angular-route.min.js` 200? You forgot to invoke IIFE? i.e `(function () {  ...})()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that you forgot to invoke the iife which registers module and controller.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('FirstController', function(){
        console.log("FirstController loaded");
    });
})();//<-- here
```

Link (in the error) talks about ngRoute as a hint only for one of the reasons your module might not have been available/instantiated when angular `ng-app` directive tried to bootstrap it. But in your case it does not even exists due to your failure to invoke the anonymous function as IIFE.

Comment: That fixed it, I'd never heard of needing to do that before. Never mentioned anywhere in the tutorials but I guess it's assumed knowledge so I'll try to read up on it. Thanks!