# AngularJS: Injection module error. Points to ui.grid. First time using it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write an angularjs app, when I run the code I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.grid due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.grid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or 
forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second 
argument.
```

The Index.cshtml file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/ui-grid.js"></script>      <- This is the reference that throw the error
    <link href="~/Content/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/scripts/fileUpload.js"></script>   <- This is my angularjs application
    <style>
        .uiGrd {
            width: 550px;
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp"
         ng-controller="myController">

        <input type="file" id="file1" name="file" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />

        <div class="uiGrd" id="grd" ui-grid="gridData"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The fileUpload.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);

app.directive('ngFiles', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var onChange = $parse(attrs.ngFiles);
        element.on('change', function (event) {
            onChange(scope, { $files: event.target.files });
        });
    };
    return {
        link: fn_link
    }
}]);
       app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
           var formdata = new FormData();
           $scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
               angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
                   formdata.append(key, value);
               });
           };

           // SEND FILES TO THE API USING POST METHOD.
           $scope.uploadFiles = function () {
               var request = {
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: '/api/fileupload/',
                   data: formdata,
                   headers: {
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   },
                   transformRequest: angular.identity
               };
               $scope.arr = new Array;
               // SEND THE FILES.
               $http(request)
                   .success(function (data) {
                       var i = 0;
                       // LOOP THROUGH DATA.
                       angular.forEach(data, function () {
                           var b = {
                               Name: data[i].Name,
                               Email: data[i].Email
                           };
                           $scope.arr.push(b);    // ADD DATA TO THE ARRAY.
                           i += 1;
                       });
                   })
                   .error(function () { });
           }
           $scope.gridData = { data: 'arr' };      // BIND ARRAY (WITH DATA) TO THE GRID.
       });
```

I am stuck with this error. Is it a misspelling problem? Am I doing the injection incorrectly?
The error occurs right away when the page opens, so I am unable to access to any of the function since this error breaks the entire code.

Can someone please offer some help?

Thank you,
Erasmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be more of syntactical error, rather than ui-grid issue.

Please follow this link:

[Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095480/failed-to-instantiate-module-myapp-due-to-error-injectornomod-http-error)